# Push notifications on expo React native app do not reach Firebase cloud messaging

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have followed the guide at  https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/push-notifications-setup/#android to implement push notifications in my React native app. I'm successfully getting the device push token and I'm using it to send a request to the FCM API like :

```
  const sendWelcomeNotification= async (token:string)=>{
    try{
      const res=  await fetch('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              Authorization: `key=AAAAtwhRX6E:APA91bEet0F1bmUk1Jelu1eoxh80t0uchzmxErUIr5Vbz5IkN4svjOwgJdHxbZtl9mwu8Hs-N8Jb1cJb9ZfZKkRElMCE3Z-m-VwDKvHMWQl_d_0tXaSA1bRA9URHdvNwLgEPbe-esDmg`,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              to: token,
              priority: 'normal',
              data: {
                experienceId: '@just_athena/tamu',
                scopeKey: '@just_athena/tamu',
                title: "Welcome to Tamu",
                message: 'We hope you find love',
              },
            }),
          });
          const data=await res.json();
          return data;
    }
    catch(e){
throw new Error(`something went wrong`)
    }
   
   }
```

The response I get from this is
`{"canonical_ids": 0, "failure": 0, "multicast_id": 5803909813247495000, "results": [{"message_id": "0:1692772583161283%72cc1f37f9fd7ecd"}], "success": 1}`

However the push notification do not seem to be delivered to my android nor to FCM.

I have created a firebase project, added google cloud messaging (legacy one) as described in expo documentation, copied the FCM token and also downloaded the google-services.json. I have confirmed that everything is correct even the package name for my app on firebase.

Here is my code starting with a custom hook useNotifications:

```
import * as Device from "expo-device";
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
import { Alert, Linking, Platform } from "react-native";
import { openSettings } from "expo-linking";

import Constants from "expo-constants";
let token=""
export const useNotifications = () => {


  const registerForPushNotificationsAsync = async () => {
    if (Device.isDevice) {
   
      const { status: existingStatus } =
        await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
      let finalStatus = existingStatus;
      if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
        const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
        finalStatus = status;
      }

      if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
     
          Alert.alert(
            "Notifications",
            "Allow Tamu to send you push notifications",
            [
              {
                text: "Deny",
              },
              {
                text: "Open Settings",
                onPress: openSettings,
              },
            ]
          );

   
        throw new Error("User doesn't allow for notifications");
      }
      token = (await Notifications.getDevicePushTokenAsync()).data;

console.log(token)
   
    } else {
      alert("Must use physical device for Push Notifications");
    }

    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("default", {
        name: "default",
        importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
        vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
        lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
      });
    }
    return token;
  };

  // This listener is fired whenever a notification is received while the app is foregrounded
  const handleNotification = (notification: Notifications.Notification) => {
    alert("received some message")
    // could be useful if you want to display your own toast message
    // could also make a server call to refresh data in other part of the app
  };

  // This listener is fired whenever a user taps on or interacts with a notification (works when app is foregrounded, backgrounded, or killed)
  const handleNotificationResponse = (
    response: Notifications.NotificationResponse
  ) => {
    alert("heyyy")
    const data: { url?: string } = response.notification.request.content.data;

    if (data?.url) Linking.openURL(data.url);
  };

  return {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync,
    handleNotification,
    handleNotificationResponse,
  };
};
```

I'm then using the hook as shown below

```
import { AsyncStorageKey } from "@app/asyncstorage/typings";
import LoveLoader from "@app/components/LoveLoader";
import { getFromStorage } from "@app/lib/app-storage";
import { useAuthenticationStatus } from "@app/lib/store";
import { focusManager } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import { AppState, AppStateStatus, Platform } from "react-native";
import GuestStack from "./navigation/stack/GuestStack";
import MatchMakeTab from "./navigation/tab/MatchMakeTab";
import { useNotifications } from "@app/hooks/useNotifications";
import { useExpoPushToken } from "@app/lib/store";
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications"
export enum Role {
    GUEST = "guest",
    USER = "user",
}

const Screens = () => {
    const setExpoPushToken=useExpoPushToken((state:any)=>state.setExpoPushToken)
    const{registerForPushNotificationsAsync,handleNotificationResponse}=useNotifications()
   const sendWelcomeNotification= async (token:string)=>{
    try{
      const res=  await fetch('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              Authorization: `key=AAAAtwhRX6E:APA91bEet0F1b..g`,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              to: token,
              priority: 'normal',
              data: {
                experienceId: '@just_athena/tamu',
                scopeKey: '@just_athena/tamu',
                title: "Welcome to Tamu",
                message: 'We hope you find love',
              },
            }),
          });
          const data=await res.json();
          return data;
    }
    catch(e){
throw new Error(`something went wrong`)
    }
   
   }
      
    useEffect(() => {
        
      registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then((data)=>{
    console.log(data)
    
        setExpoPushToken(data)
        sendWelcomeNotification(data).then((res)=>{
          console.log(res)
        })
    
      
      })
      
        Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
          handleNotification: async () => ({
            shouldShowAlert: true,
            shouldPlaySound: false,
            shouldSetBadge: true,
         
          }),
        });
        const responseListener =
        Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(
          handleNotificationResponse
        );
        
    return () => {
      if (responseListener)
        Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener);
    };
    
       
      }, []);
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);

    const isAuthenticated = useAuthenticationStatus(
        (state) => state.isAuthenticated
    );

    const setIsAuthenticated = useAuthenticationStatus(
        (state) => state.setIsAuthenticated
    );

    // const userDetailsQuery = useGetUserDetails();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            setLoading(true);
            const res = await getFromStorage(AsyncStorageKey.ACCESS_TOKEN);

            if (!res) {
                // setRole(Role.GUEST);
                setIsAuthenticated(false);
                setLoading(false);
                return;
            }

            setIsAuthenticated(true);
            setLoading(false);
        })();
    }, []);

    // const renderScreens = {
    //     guest: <GuestStack />,
    //     user: <MatchMakeTab />,
    // };

    // onlineManager.setEventListener(async (setOnline) => {
    //     // return NetInfo.addEventListener((state) => {
    //     //     setOnline(!!state.isConnected);
    //     // });

    //     const state = await NetInfo.fetch();
    //     setOnline(!!state.isConnected);
    // });

    // NetInfo.fetch().then((state) => {
    //     onlineManager.setOnline(!!state.isConnected);
    // })

    function onAppStateChange(status: AppStateStatus) {
        if (Platform.OS !== "web") {
            focusManager.setFocused(status === "active");
        }
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const subscription = AppState.addEventListener(
            "change",
            onAppStateChange
        );

        return () => subscription.remove();
    }, []);

    if (loading) return <LoveLoader />;

    return <>{isAuthenticated ? <MatchMakeTab /> : <GuestStack />}</>;
};

export default Screens;
```

My app.json looks like:

```
{
   
    "expo": {
        "name": "Tamu",
        "slug": "tamu",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "orientation": "portrait",
        "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
        "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff",
        "jsEngine": "hermes",
        "splash": {
            "image": "./assets/splash.png",
            "resizeMode": "contain",
            "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
        },
        
         
            
        
        "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
        "ios": {
            "supportsTablet": true,
            "bundleIdentifier":"com.tamu.dating",
            "infoPlist": {
                "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your photos.",
                "NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to save photos.",
                "NSCameraUsageDescription": "$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs access to your Camera."
            },
            "runtimeVersion": {
                "policy": "sdkVersion"
            }
        },
        "scheme":"com.tamu.dating",
        "android": {
            "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",

            "useNextNotificationsApi": true,
            "adaptiveIcon": {
                "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
                "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
            },
            "package": "com.tamu.dating",
            "permissions": [
                "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO",
                "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
                "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
                "android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE",
                "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
                "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
                "android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION",
                "android.permission.CAMERA"
            ],
            "runtimeVersion": "1.0.0"
        },
        "web": {
            "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
           
        },
        "extra":{
            "eas":{
                "projectId":"....-a14e-4f9f-b8d3-db84dd711090"
            }

        },
        "plugins": [
            [
                "expo-image-picker",
                {
                    "photosPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your photos",
                    "cameraPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your camera"
                }
            ],
            [
                "expo-notifications",
                {
                    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
                    "color": "#ffffff",
                    "permissions": {
                        "ios": {
                            "allowNotifications": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to send you notifications"
                        },
                        "android": {
                            "allowNotifications": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to send you notifications"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            [
                "expo-location",
                {
                    "locationAlwaysAndWhenInUsePermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to use your location."
                }
            ],
            [
                "expo-media-library",
                {
                    "photosPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your photos.",
                    "savePhotosPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to save photos.",
                    "isAccessMediaLocationEnabled": "true"
                }
            ],
            [
                "react-native-vision-camera",
                {
                    "cameraPermissionText": "$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs access to your Camera."
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
        
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
        "android_app_id": "....8213"
    
      }
}
```

Why I'm I not getting notifications?

The response I get from the FCM Rest API is
`{"canonical_ids": 0, "failure": 0, "multicast_id": 5803909813247495000, "results": [{"message_id": "0:1692772583161283%72cc1f37f9fd7ecd"}], "success": 1}` 
which is a success response.
But the notifications do not get delivered.

Comment: Are you using [firebase messaging](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage) in your app? Following this documentation I've managed to get this working fine